# Widget Registration Problem

Tags: widgets

I have created a widget to display statistics to the user. Then I create a new widget to do same thing but different parameter and I register it. Instead of creating a new widget it updates the current widget.

Both two widget's code are the same but I change the name, class and data it fetch from database to display in front-end

Thank You

Comment: it would help if we could see the code

Comment: Yes.  I think code is required for this one.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

this is maybe silly mistake.
I forget to create new parent construct to my new widget so it still use parent construct from other widget